# Testing my game in the engine works fine, I export to HTML5 and try but all the tiles in tilemap have disappeared

Tags: tilemap, html5, godot, export

Here is a link to the live game:
https://44351-w21.github.io/one-screen-platformer-francescainfranca/

As the title says all the platforms in the tilemap do not appear when you run the game on the HTML5 export. I have no missing assets, and I made sure the filenames match where they are referenced. I have no idea why this is. Any help is much appreciated.

Error in the console:

```
**ERROR**: No loader found for resource: res://Assets/Platform/grassLeft.png.
put_char @ tmp_js_export.js:8
tmp_js_export.js:8    At: core/io/resource_loader.cpp:286:_load() - Method failed. Returning: RES()
put_char @ tmp_js_export.js:8
tmp_js_export.js:8 **WARNING**: Couldn't load external resource: res://Assets/Platform/grassLeft.png
put_char @ tmp_js_export.js:8
tmp_js_export.js:8    At: scene/resources/resource_format_text.cpp:175:_parse_ext_resource() - Couldn't load external resource: res://Assets/Platform/grassLeft.png
```

Comment: Probably this issue: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/34766 - Perhaps the workaround there works for you.

Comment: @Theraot thanks for your unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: Then I'd say try to make a minimum project with that problem. Either the process of elimination leads you to the cause, or you have an issue to report in Github, and they want you to submit a minimum project to reproduce the problem.